# Datatype RouteData In ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

What are RouteData data type  and  RouteTable:

public static RouteData GetRouteDataByUrl(string url)
        {
            return RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(new RewritedHttpContextBase(url));
        }

Comment: Could you elaborate on your question? it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the metadata for the public methods and properties of both classes.  First is the RouteData class:

```
public class RouteData
{
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Web.Routing.RouteData class.
    public RouteData();

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Web.Routing.RouteData class by using
    //     the specified route and route handler.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   route:
    //     An object that defines the route.
    //
    //   routeHandler:
    //     An object that processes the request.
    public RouteData(RouteBase route, IRouteHandler routeHandler);

    // Summary:
    //     Gets a collection of custom values that are passed to the route handler but
    //     are not used when ASP.NET routing determines whether the route matches a
    //     request.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An object that contains custom values.
    public RouteValueDictionary DataTokens { get; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the object that represents a route.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An object that represents the route definition.
    public RouteBase Route { get; set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets or sets the object that processes a requested route.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An object that processes the route request.
    public IRouteHandler RouteHandler { get; set; }

    //
    // Summary:
    //     Gets a collection of URL parameter values and default values for the route.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An object that contains values that are parsed from the URL and from default
    //     values.
    public RouteValueDictionary Values { get; }

    // Summary:
    //     Retrieves the value with the specified identifier.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   valueName:
    //     The key of the value to retrieve.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     The element in the System.Web.Routing.RouteData.Values property whose key
    //     matches valueName.
    //
    // Exceptions:
    //   System.InvalidOperationException:
    //     A value does not exist for valueName.
    public string GetRequiredString(string valueName);
}
```

Second is the RoutTable class:

```
// Summary:
//     Stores the URL routes for an application.
[TypeForwardedFrom("System.Web.Routing, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=Neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35")]
public class RouteTable
{
    // Summary:
    //     Initializes a new instance of the System.Web.Routing.RouteTable class.
    [TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline this type of method across NGen image boundaries")]
    public RouteTable();

    // Summary:
    //     Gets a collection of objects that derive from the System.Web.Routing.RouteBase
    //     class.
    //
    // Returns:
    //     An object that contains all the routes in the collection.
    public static RouteCollection Routes { get; }
}
```

Do you have a more specific question about these classes?